# Ajax page load without refresh

Tags: javascript, ajax

Как загрузить страницу c помощью ajax при изменении ссылки в адресной строке, т.е. не при клике по ссылке, а именно при вбивании руками ссылки в адресной строке ?

Comment: максимум использовать `onbeforeunload`

Answer (score 1):

Ну прослушать что вбивает пользователь скорее всего не получится , а вот если он зафиксировал ввод , то можно тупо слушать что там в адресной строке происходит :

```
//Валидные хэши для которых требуется выполнить запрос
var pages = {
    "page1" : "page1-url" , 
    "page2" : "page2-url" , 
    "page3" : "page3-url"
}
//обработчик измененного хэша
var hashHandler = function () {
      var ajaxPage = window.location.hash.replace("#" , "");
      //если ключ есть в объекте страниц выполняем запрос 
      if(pages[ajaxPage]){
            console.log("run ajax request " + pages[ajaxPage]);
      }
      return false;
}

//подписываемся на событие изменения хэша
window.addEventListener("hashchange", hashHandler, false);
```